# Getting a list of parents from a List?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'm writing a little C# program to scan a directory recursively and get the filesize of each file, a few other bits of information, and add it all to tables in a sqlite database. I've hit a bit of a snag, however - I want to get the directory data (Table structure below) and turn it into a List< Class > the Class being a class with the file data, directory data **and** a List of all of the directory's parents in order (Parent, grand parent, etc.).

Directory table:

```
id int
parentID int
directoryName string
```

How would I go about doing this? Getting a list of children is simple, but I'm finding that getting a list of parents is fairly difficult without repeatedly looping through the directory list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `List<Class>`  is not the right class to use.

Depending on what you are going to do with your list, I would use a `Dictionary<int, Class>` if the order of your list is not important, otherwise `SortedDictionary<int, Class>` if you want it to be ordered by ID, or `OrderedDictionary` if you want to be able to specify a different way of sorting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DirectoryInfo.GetParent()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getparent.aspx)

```
List<DirectoryInfo> parents = new List<DirectoryInfo>();
DirectoryInfo parent = di.Parent;
while(parent != null){
      parents.Add(parent);
      parent = di.Parent;
}
```

Comment: I should have clarified, I need the ID of the parent in the table - so just forgot that I mentioned directories at all, and pretend we're working with a long line of single parent children.